# Azure Management API for KeyVaults metadata

Tags: azure

Please help to find a possibility to list all available secrets, keys and certificates via Management API from Key Vault.

I've found the following request:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_ID}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vault_name}/secrets?api-version=2018-02-14"
```

Unfortunately, it lists only secrets.

For keys and certificates I've just found next:

```
GET {vaultBaseUrl}/keys?api-version=7.0

GET {vaultBaseUrl}/certificates?api-version=7.0
```

Do you know a possibility to list all keys and certificates from management API?

Ideally, I need to list all metadata from a keyVault in one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible in a single call.  Secrets, Keys, and Certificates are different entities, and the methods to list have separate concerns and return objects with different schemata.

You'll need to extract the information you need from each call.

Comment: Thank for the comment. What do you think about making request via management.azure.com request instead of VaultBaseUrl?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the management API is a wrapper for the resource specific APIs.  You can see an example response in the following link which only returns the methods you're able to perform on the secrets, keys and certificates: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/get